# No dropdown arrow to select target branch when merging in visual studio 2019

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019, source-control-explorer

In visual studio, I'm working in a branch and want to merge downward into my branch.  However when I try to merge down, where it asks for source and target branch, there is no dropdown arrow to select a different target branch.

I've tried resizing the window, making it full screen, restarting my PC, making sure Visual Studio 2019 is up to date, pretty much everything I can think of.  Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

The image tag doesn't seem to be working, but here is a URL to a screenshot of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbVAD.jpg

[image: Text]

Comment: Hi @Kevin Lu-MSFT, thanks a bunch for your response!  So sorry for not getting back with you, I kind of forgot about this, as I just got someone else to do the merge for me.  Any way, now 2 weeks later I went to try your suggestion and sure enough there was a drop down arrow, and the browse button there.  I have no idea what the fix could have been as so much time has passed, and I didn't see when it was back.  I'll be sure to try this though if it ever happens again.  Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, I couldn't reproduce this issue on my machine.

It could work as expected in Visual Studio (version: `16.4.0 , 16.7.5, 16.7.6`)

Here is the expected Tool screenshot:

[image]

From your screenshot, not only the drop-down arrow, it doesn’t seem to show the `Browse option`.

As far as I know, the way the machine’s screen is displayed may cause this issue.

You could navigate to `Windows Settings -> System -> Display -> Scale and layout` and change the settings.

Here is my screen setting, you could refer to it:

[image]

You can reduce the enlarged scale to check if it works.